# Overide a CSS already loaded

Tags: css

I need to code a plugin for WP to replace (depending on the path) an specific image of a CSS already loaded.
What are the best practices to do that?

The way I code it is:

```
<style>
    header > .logo {
    background: url("https://www.google.com/logos/2018/snowgames_luge/cta.png") no-repeat 0 0 !important;
    }
</style>
```

Thank

Comment: write a code that works? as the question is right now it is so open ended it is basically worthless. First try to write the code yourself, than ask a question about your code. If there are concepts you do not understand, ask directly about those concepts.

Comment: Have you already created [a child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/)?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Child Theme. Add this to the styles.css file in the child theme:

```
 header > .logo {
    background: url("https://www.example.com/path/to/the/new/image.png") no-repeat 0 0 !important;
    }
```

Since the Child Theme CSS will load after the parent theme CSS, this should override the first setting, even if it is also set to `!important` .